# no tutorial in Librviz: Incorporating RViz into a Custom GUI

Tags: ros, librviz, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.I want to  learn how to write an application using an RViz visualization widget but [the link](http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html)  in this page was unuseable. Could somen one give me an availble link? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276281/no-tutorial-in-librviz:-incorporating-rviz-into-a-custom-gui/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The redirects have stopped working for some reason.

Try: [docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-11-20**:
Thanks.I also found it in a Chinese blog.Thanks anyway!